# Global Hotkeys - C#

Tags: c#, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-hook

I have built an application which listens for a global hot key (Alt + Space currently), when I press the hot key when Google Chrome is in focus it brings my app to focus but also opens Chrome's context menu (right click menu). I used the following dll for [implementing the keyboard hook](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C).

Can I prevent this from happening? If so how? This isn't a major problem but if there is a way in which you can clear all existing hot keys tied to that combination then I'd like to learn this.

**EDIT**

The answer that I selected as being the correct one, is the correct one but for my problem. To correctly implement this feature into a C# WinForm i used this tutorial which was very helpful: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/180436-global-hotkeys/

Comment: "implementing the keyboard hook" that's your problem. Use `RegisterHotkey` instead of abusing keyboard hooks. There is a number of duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A445517+registerhotkey&submit=search

Comment: @CodeInChaos just implemented the RegisterHotkey method into my application a much cleaner method, going to update my question with your suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FAQ section of the linked article contains your answer:

> **Question**
>
> I need to suppress some keystrokes after I have processed them.
>
> **Answer**
>
> Just set the `e.Handled` property to `true` in the key events you have
>   processed. It prevents the keystrokes being processed by other
>   applications.

Comment: Fixes the immediate problem, but still clearly the wrong solution.

Comment: @CodeInChaos - Of course, but I answered the question asked. The question is very direct. I was actually writing a comment to support your suggestion of using `RegisterHotkey`. I guess that isn't necessary now.